# synchronizing thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am implementing java `Runnable` interface for multithreading. I have some `n`  number of threads. Each of the thread has its own life. I would like to wait till life of all the threads get expire. Lets say following is the case

```
for(int i = 0; i< k;i++){
 Thread thread1 = new Thread(new xyz())
 Thread thread2 = new Thread(new abc())
 Thread thread3 = new Thread(new mno())
 thread1.start();
 thread2.start();
 thread3.start();
}
```

I am doing following to synchronize it. I don't know if it is correct. Please let me know how would I do it? And is there any way to check, if my threaded program is working correctly?

```
          if(thread2.isAlive())
                try {
                    thread2.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            if(thread1.isAlive())
                    try {
                        thread1.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            if(thread3.isAlive())
                try {
                        thread3.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add your Runnables to an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and call [shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) / [awaitTermination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) which will return once all tasks have completed. There are a few examples in the javadoc - in summary you would write something like:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

executor.submit(runnable1);
executor.submit(runnable2);
executor.submit(runnable3);

executor.shutdown();
boolean allRunnableAreDone = executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// This line is reached once all runnables have finished their job
// or the 60 second timeout has expired
```

Comment: It's a good idea to inspect the return value of `awaitTermination` and loop on it, just in case it takes longer than your time specified to complete.

Comment: Or to call `awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, ...)` as opposed to just 60 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Although the `ExecutorService` answer from @assylias is a good one, here's more information about `join()`.

You do not need to test the `isAlive()` before you `join()`.  The `Thread.join()` code already does that.  Here's a snippet from the code there:

```
while (isAlive()) {
    wait(0);
}
```

So all you need to do is join with your threads:

```
   try {
       thread2.join();
       thread1.join();
       thread3.join();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // always a good pattern
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: I didn't knew this one. This seems to be the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple solution you could put all of your threads in a List then call join on them after they have been started:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i< k;i++)
{
  //create threads
  Thread thread1 = new Thread(new xyz());
  Thread thread2 = new Thread(new abc());
  Thread thread3 = new Thread(new mno());

  //store threads
  threads.add(thread1);
  threads.add(thread2);
  threads.add(thread3);

  //start threads
  thread1.start();
  thread2.start();
  thread3.start();
}

//join all threads
for(Thread t : threads)
   t.join();

//You are here after all threads have terminated
```

Answer (score 1):

Java contains mechanism to do this kind of things in [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

In your case, you probably need [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination)

Answer (score 1):

The `join()` method does not join on a thread, but on a lock object. The waiting thread must call `lockObject.join()` and the working thread must call `lockObject.notify()` when it is done. The waiting thread will be notified and can continue its work. You also need `synchronize` blocks around these calls.

I also recommend the Executor like assylias mentioned, it is much easier than implementing this behaviour by yourself.